# 99 Pontiac sunfire

Tags: pontiac, sunfire

First when u try to turn the key to start it all the lights work just fine but a further turn to start nothing not even a click we tried jumping it across using the starter worked for a day then nothing now it acts like there's no fuel getting to it will run just for a split second using a screwdriver across the selonoid but diesimmediately btw new starter battery coil pack engine was just rebuilt and the fuel pump I can hear it kicking on Everytime I turn the key I'm lost

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you do use the screwdriver across the solenoid, the engine will turn over, but it's not firing. Am I understanding you correctly?